# Check if one array is a permutated version of another array

Tags: java

I want to check whether array B is permutation of array A.

I thought it can be done using 1 `for`-loop, however I saw different sources that most of them told me to use 2 `for`-loops.

```
for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
    boolean found = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < B.length; j++)
        if (B[j] == A[i]) { 
            found = true;
            break; 
        }
        assert(found);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < B.length; i++) {
        boolean found = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < A.length; j++)
            if (A[j] == B[i]) { 
                found = true; 
                break; 
            }
        assert(found);
    }
```

Is this a correct implementation with 2 `for`-loops?

By the way, why I had to perform 2 `for`-loops where first one is comparing B with A, then the second one A with B?

Comment: `O(N * log(N))` solution: sort out both arrays and check if `A[i] = B[i]` for all `i`-s

Comment: The canonical method is to sort both arrays and then check if the sorted arrays are equal to each other. In your case, the first pair of loops checks if all elements of A are in B and the second pair checks if all elements of B are in A. You can drop the second pair and instead check if A and B are of equal length.

Comment: This implementation is incorrect, since it can't correctly handle duplicated values. This code "says", that `A = {1, 2}` and `B = {1, 1, 1, 2}` are fine, even though it isn't true.

Comment: It also returns true for `A = {1, 2, 2}`, `B = {1, 1, 2}`, so adding a length check doesn't fix it, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code splits the permutation check into two operations:

1. for each element `A[i]` check if `A[i]` appears in `B`
2. for each element `B[j]` check if `B[j]` appears in `A`

As noted by @Tom, this doesn't work in the general case, because it ignores duplicate elements.

It is also inefficient. The second part can be omitted, if one checks `A.length == B.length` before anything else, but the remainder is still `O(n²)`. And it's still wrong, because it returns false positives when considering duplicate elements.

The --more or less-- canonical method is to simply sort both arrays and compare them for equality:

```
Arrays.sort(A);
Arrays.sort(B);
assert(Arrays.equals(A, B));
```

Sorting is generally know to be `O(n ln n)`, so the whole operation is now more efficient than before. It also makes things a whole lot more readable.

Comment: This has the disadvantage, that array `A` and `B` need to be cloned first, to avoid side effects (if these arrays are used somewhere else). Btw a suitable way to fix the "duplicate values" problem is to let the inner loop start from `i` (i.e. `for (int j = i; j < ....; j++)`). This wouldn't be `O(n²)` anymore. But I still agree, that sorting is the generally better approach for checking any kind of permutation (e.g. array, String, ...).

Comment: @Tom For what it's worth, the [reference implementation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/is_permutation/) for c++ does explicit occurrence counting and demands an `O(n²)` worst case.

Comment: So if I input the value of the array manually for A and B with same length and all distinct, I can just remove the second for loop? Thanks.

Comment: @MasAdam I am a little too lazy right now to prove it, but yes. If `A.length == B.length`, `A` contains only distinct values, and every element from `A` is contained in `B`, then `A` is a permutation of `B` and vice versa.

Comment: @MasAdam To be honest, I wouldn't rely on the fact that `A` contains distinct values, because this can change in a later version of your application. So your algorithm would be broken again. The more stable version would be the one suggested by 'dhke'.

Comment: @dhke That's okay, you don't need to prove it. I got the overall concept already :)

Comment: @Tom Yeah I think you are right, this is not a really good function.

Comment: @MasAdam But it was a good first version and you learned from it. That's all that counts :D.